# package or namespace load failed for 'shiny'

Tags: r, shiny

When I am trying to install shiny in R studio I am getting this error

> there is no package called 'httpuv'

, so I tried using `package.install('httpuv')` but here I got something like

> In install.packages("httpuv") :
> installation of package 'httpuv' had non-zero exit status

After that I tried to `library(shiny)` to get load shiny but still got the same error that httpuv is missing below.

```
library(shiny)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'shiny' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called 'httpuv'
```

Comment: Can you show your `R` version

Comment: " here I got something like"  - don't guess ... if you didnt pay full attention first time around; try to install httpuv again; and read the errors carefully....

Answer (score 0):

I tried simply upgrading the R version and it worked